# Floating button with unorderedlist

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 part question.

1. How can I align the unordered list (Google and Facebook icon) from right to left with its parent list item when hovered. (currently when the parent list item is hovered Google and Facebook icon always align with the first list item)
2. How do I center the Facebook and Google icon in the middle.
3. When the mouse is moved to the Facebook or Google icon the original unordered list disappears. How can I fix this.

Code Snippet below:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.label-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 48px;
  right: 105px;
  display: table;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-text {
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.label-arrow {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #333;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.float {
  position: fixed;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  background-color: #F33;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index: 1000;
  animation: bot-to-top 2s ease-out;
}

.ul {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  bottom: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.ul1 {
  position: fixed;
  right: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  bottom: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.ul .li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ul1 .li1 {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ul .li a img {
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.ul1 .li1 a {
  background-color: #F33;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  
}

.ul:hover, .ul1:hover {
  visibility: visible!important;
  opacity: 1!important;
}

 

.my-float {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

a.menu-share+.ul, a.menu-share1+.ul1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}


a.menu-share:hover+.ul, a.menu-share1:hover+.ul1 {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: scale-in 0.5s;
}

a.menu-share i {
  animation: rotate-in 0.5s;
}

a.menu-share:hover>i {
  animation: rotate-out 0.5s;
}

@keyframes bot-to-top {
  0% {
    bottom: -40px
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 40px
  }
}

@keyframes scale-in {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-in {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-out {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#" class="float menu-share">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o my-float"></i>
</a>
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li">
    <a href="#" class="menu-share1">
      <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg" class="my-float" />
    </a>

    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li1">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus my-float"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="li1">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook my-float"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <a href="#" class="menu-share1">
      <img src="http://mblogthumb1.phinf.naver.net/20121009_136/dogtalk__1349752474508pRuyE_JPEG/Puppy-Love-29817_large.jpg?type=w2" class="my-float" />
    </a>
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li1">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus my-float"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="li1">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook my-float"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that one. I rewrote the code a bit. The main idea about centering text elements is that you specify `line-height` equal to element's height, but there are shouldn't be any paddings.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.label-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 48px;
  right: 105px;
  display: table;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-text {
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.label-arrow {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #333;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.float {
  position: fixed;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  background-color: #F33;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index: 1000;
  animation: bot-to-top 2s ease-out;
}

.ul {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  bottom: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.ul1, .ul2 {
  position: fixed;
  right: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.ul1 {
  bottom: 80px;
}

.ul2 {
  bottom: 120px;
}

.ul .li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ul1 .li1 {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ul .li a img {
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.ul1 .li1 a {
  background-color: #F33;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.ul:hover, .ul1:hover {
  visibility: visible!important;
  opacity: 1!important;
}

a.menu-share+.ul, a.menu-share1+.ul1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}


a.menu-share:hover+.ul, a.menu-share1:hover+.ul1 {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: scale-in 0.5s;
}

a.menu-share i {
  animation: rotate-in 0.5s;
}

a.menu-share:hover>i {
  animation: rotate-out 0.5s;
}

@keyframes bot-to-top {
  0% {
    bottom: -40px
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 40px
  }
}

@keyframes scale-in {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-in {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-out {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#" class="float menu-share">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o my-float"></i>
</a>
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li">
    <a href="#" class="menu-share1">
      <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg" class="my-float" />
    </a>

    <ul class="ul1 ul2">
      <li class="li1">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus my-float"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="li1">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook my-float"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <a href="#" class="menu-share1">
      <img src="http://mblogthumb1.phinf.naver.net/20121009_136/dogtalk__1349752474508pRuyE_JPEG/Puppy-Love-29817_large.jpg?type=w2" class="my-float" />
    </a>
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li1">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus my-float"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="li1">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook my-float"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```